# How to use class in javascript

Tags: javascript

I declared a class in file A:

```
A = function(param1,para2){};
```

Then i used the class in file B:

```
 let A = require('../filename'); 
 let a = new A(param1,param2);
```

But the V8 said that,The A is not defined
    How can i fix it ? 
    Thanks in regards.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to export it.

Comment: You need to `export` `A` in the file

Comment: you mean like thie ? export A = function(p1,p2). then i got this error: A is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using CommonJS style modules, then you can add it to the `module.exports` to be able to require it in B.

A

```
let A = function(param1,para2){};
module.exports = A;
```

B

```
 let A = require('../filename'); 
 let a = new A(param1,param2);
```